# How to do a CV in french

Tags: cv

This is my CV template that I want : https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk

But although I added the command  "\usepackage[french,main=french]{babel}", the titles of profilsection are not in French, because I need to do my cv in french not in English

Comment: Hi, as I understand it is example from **overleaf**, so give a link because Your code too large and not full

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh thanks, I edit my question and I add the link of the template

Comment: As far as I can see there are no hardcoded texts in the class your example uses (thus it is not coupled with `babel`), so all the english names are all in `template.tex` and you'll have to manually translate all of it.

Answer (score 2):

Opening the source of the class you are referring to ([link](https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV)), the class has no option to automatically translate the headings into French or load the French synonyms, at the present time. So you may choose to edit the source for your own usage and translate the headings and main text.

About writing multi-language documents and fonts, the git source has a reference which I copy exactly for your reference.

> When working on multi-language documents, I highly advise against the
> usage of pdfLaTeX. Since I have only little experience with LuaLaTeX
> (but will probably switch to the latter soon), I can only provide
> instructions for XeLaTeX for now. There you first need to load the
> polyglossia package and set fonts for each language separately. For
> latin-based documents with e.g. some arabic text snippets then use

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
% typeset arabic snippets in body text with either of
\textarabic{...}
\begin{Arabic}...\end{Arabic}
```